# How should I get ActiveSync / Mobile Dev Center to recognise my Windows CE device via USB?

Tags: installation, usb, activesync

We develop a custom Windows CE-based device. To connect this to the PC via ActiveSync / Mobile Device Center, we have to set up entries so that the WCE USB Serial Host (wceusbsh.sys) recognises our Vendor ID (Vid) and Product ID (Pid).

To do this, to date, we have distributed a modified version of wceusbsh.inf and wceusbsh.sys: when the user first connects the device then ActiveSync basically says it does not recognise the device, and the user is  asked to identify a driver for it. If they now point at the location where they've stored our wceusbsh.* files then all is well. However this is pretty clunky.

What we really want is a slick way to do this, preferably by running an installer which just gets everything ready, so that as soon as the device is plugged in it is recognised by wceusbsh.sys.

Any clues how to do this? There seem to be a ton of registry entries which relate to WCEUSBSH, and it's not clear how these are set: just "installing" the .INF file doesn't seem to allow for setting them all, so it does look like ActiveSync reads the .INF file and then adds some more information before appending the new info to the Registry.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in case anyone else comes looking for an answer to this, we managed to do it via this link from MSDN [WinUSB (Windows Driver Kit)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff540196.aspx). We now have a driver install program which sets up USB / Mobile Device Center so that when you plug in the CE device it is recognised correctly.